# Attempting to find minimum value in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array with ten values and I am looking to loop through the array and store the lowest value in a variable but I keep getting `0.0` outputted even though the smallest number is `3`.

Here is my attempt:

```
  static void  lowestStudentAvgMark() {
    double [] averagesArray = new double[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]+studentMarksArray[i][1]+studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
      averagesArray[i] = total;
    }
    double min = averagesArray[0];
    for (int counter = 1; counter < averagesArray.length; counter++) {
      if (averagesArray[counter] < min) {
        min = averagesArray[counter];
      }
    }
    System.out.println(min);
  }
```

Comment: where does `studentMarksArray` get initialized? Are you sure that you're properly populating your `averagesArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `for` loop read `1` less, than actual number. So, the last index value of `averagesArray` is `0`. So, you got minimum number as `0`.

```
for(int i = 0; i< averagesArray.length; i++){ //Use averagesArray.length

   double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]+
             studentMarksArray[i][1]+studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
      averagesArray[i] = total;
}
```

Comment: Good. It was very small.

Answer (score 1):

Use the length of the array to loop-

```
for(int i = 0; i < averagesArray.length; i++) {

}
```

It will read from 0 'til the length. You used **i < 9** when your array has a size of 10.